# Unable to upload data on firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload a simple form data on firebase but thing is that I am not even getting any error or any data uploaded or confirmation alert box.

Any suggestions where I went wrong ?

I am using firebase real time database and followed it's documentation

This is link of real time database of my firebase.

> https://iet-workshop.firebaseio.com/

```js
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var msg = document.getElementById("comment");

function submitClick(){
 

 var nameTxt = name.value;
 var emailTxt = email.value;
 var msgTxt = msg.value;

 writeUserData(nameTxt,emailTxt,msgTxt);

}

function writeUserData(name, email, msg) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    comment : msg
  }, function(error){
   if(error){
    // write failed
    alert("Sorry unable to write data error = ",error);
   }else{
    // data saved successfully
    alert("Thanks for your feedback");
   }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
 background: royalblue;
}

.form-style-6{
 font: 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 padding: 16px;
 background: #F7F7F7;
}
.form-style-6 h1{
 background: #43D1AF;
 padding: 20px 0;
 font-size: 140%;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 margin: -16px -16px 16px -16px;
}
.form-style-6 input[type="text"],
.form-style-6 input[type="date"],
.form-style-6 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-6 input[type="email"],
.form-style-6 input[type="number"],
.form-style-6 input[type="search"],
.form-style-6 input[type="time"],
.form-style-6 input[type="url"],
.form-style-6 textarea,
.form-style-6 select 
{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 4%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 3%;
 color: #555;
 font: 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-6 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-6 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-6 textarea:focus,
.form-style-6 select:focus
{
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #43D1AF;
 padding: 3%;
 border: 1px solid #43D1AF;
}

.form-style-6 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-6 input[type="button"]{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 3%;
 background: #43D1AF;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #30C29E;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-left-style: none; 
 color: #fff;
}
.form-style-6 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-6 input[type="button"]:hover{
 background: #2EBC99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>IET Workshop</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-style-6">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <form>
   <input id="name" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Your Name" />
   <input id="email" type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Email Address" />
   <textarea id="comment" name="field3" placeholder="Type your Message"></textarea>
   <input id='submitBtn' type="submit" value="Send" onclick="submitClick()" />
  </form>
 </div>
</body>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyD83SJTFRLbWE2oh8ov7IPBBNQaSX_kpBs",
    authDomain: "iet-workshop.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://iet-workshop.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "iet-workshop",
    storageBucket: "iet-workshop.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "569222277610"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: From your code I can see variable 'userId' defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a typical situation of a rules not allowing access to your database. Check the rules and make sure that it allows Write

```
"rules": 
{
         ".read": true,
         ".write": true,
}
```